Why Goldstone Bosons in QCD act as the effective long distance mediators?
QCD breaks axial generators spontaneously, as $m(u)  <  m(d) << Λ_{QCD}$ and  for energies much less than  $Λ_{QCD}$, the theory which predicts this spontaneous breaking (QCD) is already confined. So this approximation holds for all QCD (which lives for energies higher than $\Lambda_{QCD})$.
As such, 3 pseudo Goldstone Bosons ("pseudo", since m(u) ~ m(d) $\gtrsim$ 0 in "reality". This means they have small mass) are created.   The broken charges are axial, so we need pseudoscalars to represent them.
Theoretically, there is no doctor prescribing the chiral condensate to be $\neq 0$. We postulate it's $\neq$ 0, as we experimentally observe that, given a hadron, another one which differs by parity only, doesn't exist. This is just a reductio ad absurdum by dictating that chiral symmetry  not be broken; however, it holds a lot of intuition.
Given the fact that chiral spontaneous breaking doesn't stem from the Hamiltonian, but has to be postulated, is there a way to understand why is it the Goldstone Bosons which become the effective mediator when QCD is already confined?

Your question and picture of χSB is all over the map, so, instead,  I'll provide  my best answer to one such I'd ask approximating yours.
Indeed, the QCD Hamiltonian approximately realizes the chiral $SU(2)\times SU(2)$ chiral symmetry you are talking about (ignoring heavier quarks) always; linearly for distances smaller than $1/\Lambda_{QCD}$, where I have conflated the χSB scale with the confinement scale (they are close, and you do not care about the interstitial region, a fascinating place involving pions and quarks).
However, this Hamiltonian does dictate its own vacuum; thereby requiring that, for hadronic distances (larger than $1/\Lambda_{QCD}$), this vacuum is not invariant under the three axial transformations; but only (almost$^\natural$) invariant under only three generators of the above, the vector ones (isospin), closing into an SU(2) subgroup of $SU(2)\times SU(2)$; unlike the three axial ones, now realized nonlinearly in the effective Hamiltonian in the Nambu-Goldstone mode of (almost) massless pion dynamics.
As a consequence of this χSB breaking, the three pseudogoldstons (pions) are untypically light for hadrons (mesons mediating long- range strong interactions between hadrons), underlying nuclear potentials.

However, as you might know, pions only dominate the long-range tails of such potentials, while the heavier mesons dominate the shorter-range nuclear forces!



$^\natural$ Isospin is an almost good symmetry of the strong interactions for $m(u)\sim 2$MeV, $m(d)\sim 5 $MeV, $\Lambda_{QCD}\sim 300$MeV, since the isospin breaking parameter $(m(d)- m(u))/\Lambda_{QCD}$ is so tiny. 

So, to sum up roughly, we could consider each hadron as a mediator at the right distance? It seems all u-d mesons were picked but strange ones. I suppose it's just for SU(3) flavour breaking not being that good, but in principle we could consider even a Kaon as a mediator. What I mean is that Goldstone Bosons are not mediators for theoretical reason, but just because they are light. In addition π Goldstone Bosons come from SU(2) flavour simmetry breaking, which is the least approximate simmetry breaking we have. So it's mostly them we consider, solely for these reasons

Roughly, yes. The Goldstone nature of mediators is irrelevant, as the longest range is dominated by the lightest particles. K mesons have to be considered in zero strangeness pairs, as strangeness is conserved in the strong interactions.
